Efficient way to order Annotate field in DRF
I have three models in models.py,
class AAA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)

class BBB(models.Model):
    aaa = models.ForeignKey(AAA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)

class CCC(models.Model):
    aaa = models.ForeignKey(AAA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)

and I want to order in views.py,
class AAAListCreateView(generics.ListAPIView):
    class AAAPagination(CursorPagination):
        page_size = 2

    queryset = AAA.objects.all().annotate(
        b_count=Count("bbb", distinct=True),
        c_count=Count("ccc", distinct=True),
        total=F('b_count')+('c_count')
    )
    serializer_class = AAAListSerializer
    pagination_class = AAAPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = AAAListFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ['b_count', 'c_count', 'total']
    ordering = 'b_count'

The problems that I want to ask are...

I want to descending all of my ordering_fields. Descending order without specifying -.
In views.py, I annotate all of my ordering_fields. But I think it is not efficient way because it fetches all sorting annotate fields.

What should I do?

You left out the ShortForm model. But, let me get this straight: You want to sort with one of these (-b_count, -c_count OR -total) and if you passed the "sort by -b_count" url flag you don't want get the -c_count annotation. Am I in the right ballpark?- Or, I guess i'm confused with #2.. are you worried about using an unneeded anotation?- or are you worried about annotating .all() everytime, even when there's a .filter()?

@Nealium Oh sorry. I forgot to change the model name. I corrected this part.

@Nealium And.... in my real code, there are more annotate fields for ordering, and I get unnecessary annotate fields every time even though they are not used for ordering.
For example, if I order only c_count, I would like to call only c_count, not b_count and total field.

Do you filter by these annotated fields?- or are they only used for Ordering?

@Nealium they are just for ordering.

I was mistaken: OrderingFilter is a built in feature with Django-Rest-Framework and is not specific to django-filter. When searching that keyword in vanilla drf docs, no reference of it showed up for me.
Using DRF it's the same general idea, override OrderingFilter the main difference is the method is actually called filter_queryset
Updated version with vanilla Django-Rest-Framework:
Custom Ordering Filter [edited]

{project_root}/utils/rest_filters_overrides.py
Note: I ran this through ruff, but haven't tested it
TODO: Actual annotations in def filter_queryset

from django.db.models import Count, F
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter


class FancyOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    """OrderingFilter Override, always descending order + dynamic annotate"""

    def always_descend(self, ordering):
        """
        Custom Method. Ensure all orderings are descending.

        Note:
            It's done in a custom method so it can be used in
            `get_default_ordering` AND `get_ordering`. Could be done without the
            method and possibly in a smarter way.
        """
        new_order = []
        for param in ordering:
            if not param.startswith("-"):
                new_order.append(f"-{param}")
            else:
                new_order.append(param)
        return new_order

    def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
        """Override order, always descend"""
        params = request.query_params.get(self.ordering_param)
        if params:
            fields = [param.strip() for param in params.split(",")]
            ordering = self.remove_invalid_fields(
                queryset, fields, view, request
            )
            if ordering:
                return self.always_descend(ordering)  # <- extra call

        # No ordering was included, or all the ordering fields were invalid
        return self.get_default_ordering(view)

    def get_default_ordering(self, view):
        """Override default ordering to ensure it's descending"""
        ordering = getattr(view, "ordering", None)
        if isinstance(ordering, str):
            if ordering.startswith("-"):  # <- new if
                return (ordering,)
            return (f"-{ordering}",)  # <- new f string
        return self.always_descend(ordering)  # <- extra call

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        """Override filter, dynamically annotate"""
        ordering = self.get_ordering(  # <- call override
            request, queryset, view
        )

        if ordering:
            annotate_dict = {}
            if "-total" in ordering:
                annotate_dict["b_count"] = Count("bbb", distinct=True)
                annotate_dict["c_count"] = Count("ccc", distinct=True)
                annotate_dict["total"] = F("b_count") + ("c_count")
            if "-b_count" in ordering and "-b_count" not in annotate_dict:
                annotate_dict["b_count"] = Count("bbb", distinct=True)
            if "-c_count" in ordering and "-c_count" not in annotate_dict:
                annotate_dict["c_count"] = Count("ccc", distinct=True)

            # NOTE: `**` on a dict turns them into keyword args
            #   I personally like this trick as it's only a single `.filter()`
            #   or `.annotate()` call
            queryset = queryset.annotate(**annotate_dict)

            return queryset.order_by(*ordering)

        return queryset

    def get_template_context(self, request, queryset, view):
        """
        Override template context, so options are correct.
        Not sure if this method is important :shrugs:
        """
        current = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        current = None if not current else current[0]
        options = []
        context = {
            "request": request,
            "current": current,
            "param": self.ordering_param,
        }
        for key, label in self.get_valid_fields(queryset, view, context):
            options.append(
                (key, "%s - %s" % (label, _("descending")))  # <- changed
            )
            options.append(("-" + key, "%s - %s" % (label, _("descending"))))
        context["options"] = options
        return context

New Viewset
from utils.rest_filters_overrides import FancyOrderingFilter

class AAAListCreateView(generics.ListAPIView):
    class AAAPagination(CursorPagination):
        page_size = 2

    queryset = AAA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AAAListSerializer
    pagination_class = AAAPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, FancyOrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = AAAListFilterSet
    ordering_fields = ['b_count', 'c_count', 'total']
    ordering = 'b_count'

.all() annotate question
Now the filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, FancyOrderingFilter] makes me think it literally runs base_qs -> DjangoFilterBackend -> FancyOrderingFilter. So if you could do a print(qs.count()) inside that FancyOrderingFilter.filter method and validate it against AAA.objects.all().count() that would be cool. I hope so!- cause that means we're done, minus the normal debugging.

Original (django-filter)
So because you're using django-filter, to do the ordering, the move might be to override that OrderingFilter class.. mainly looking at that filter() method
This is what i've come up with. It would need more work to make it more dynamic if this is a common issue for you. For 1-2 cases, in theory, it should work:
Custom Ordering Filter

{project_root}/utils/django_filters_overrides.py
Note: I ran this through ruff, but haven't tested it
TODO: Actual annotations in def filter

from django.db.models import Count, F
from django.forms.utils import pretty_name
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django_filters import OrderingFilter
from django_filters.constants import EMPTY_VALUES

class FancyOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    """OrderingFilter Override, always descending order + dynamic annotate"""

    def get_ordering_value(self, param):
        """Override order, always descend"""

        # Keep all this so actually putting "-" still works
        descending = param.startswith("-")
        param = param[1:] if descending else param
        field_name = self.param_map.get(param, param)

        # return "-%s" % field_name if descending else field_name
        return "-%s" % field_name # always descend

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        """Override filter, dynamically annotate"""
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            return qs

        ordering = [
            self.get_ordering_value(param)  # <- call override
            for param in value
            if param not in EMPTY_VALUES
        ]

        # manually annotate (sucks, but you've only got to do it once!)
        annotate_dict = {}
        if "-total" in ordering:
            annotate_dict["b_count"] = Count("bbb", distinct=True)
            annotate_dict["c_count"] = Count("ccc", distinct=True)
            annotate_dict["total"] = F("b_count")+("c_count")
        if "-b_count" in ordering and "-b_count" not in annotate_dict:
            annotate_dict["b_count"] = Count("bbb", distinct=True)
        if "-c_count" in ordering and "-c_count" not in annotate_dict:
            annotate_dict["c_count"] = Count("ccc", distinct=True)

        # NOTE: `**` on a dict turns them into keyword args
        #   I personally like this trick as it's only a single `.filter()` or
        #   `.annotate()` call
        qs = qs.annotate(**annotate_dict)

        # Normal Django ordering
        return qs.order_by(*ordering)

    def build_choices(self, fields, labels):
        """
        Override build choices, so labels are correct.
        See source, this no_dash label.get() is iffy.
        Not sure if this method is important :shrugs:
        """
        no_dash = [
            (param, labels.get("%s" % param, self.descending_fmt % labels.get(
                field, _(pretty_name(param))
            )))
            for field, param in fields.items()
        ]
        with_dash = [
            ("-%s" % param, labels.get("-%s" % param, self.descending_fmt % label))
            for param, label in no_dash
        ]

        # interleave the no dash and with dash choices
        return [val for pair in zip(no_dash, with_dash) for val in pair]


Thank you for helping me a lot.
However, I have error with ['FancyOrderingFilter' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset'], so I fixed it [from django_filters import OrderingFilter] to [from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter]. But it causes error with FieldError, that is cannot resolve keyword total into field. In FancyOrderingFilter.filter, I've tried using any print in it, but it doesn't seem to be looking up, so I think that filter method is not working. What should I do?

@chocho I've edited my answer with the correct override. I was unaware OrderingFilter
was a django-rest-framework feature, it didn't show up anywhere in the Docs when
I searched it! I'm sorry for sending you on a goose chase!- I should have
checked the DRF source code before googling + finding django-filters :(

@chocho Btw I really do recommend checking out the source code links. Being comfortable
just git clone-ing a package's github project and using "global find" + "Go to Definition"
to figure out anything-and-everything is such a useful skill! It's basically all
I did lol
